# Necesito ayuda para configurar MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un sitio web de carácter educativo que con el presente confinamiento ha disparado su número de visitas (sirve para que profesores envíen ejercicios a sus alumnos y éstos les devuelvan sus respuestas).

He ampliado el servidor (máquina virtual en google cloud, con windows server) hasta 36 vCPUs y 160GB de memoria, pero no sé configurar el archivo my.ini adecuadamente.
La aplicación es intensiva tanto en lecturas como escrituras en la base de datos. 
Mi problema es que en las horas punta (de lunes a jueves por la mañana) cuando pasa de 25000 usuarios activos (según google analytics) el servidor mysql se bloquea y lo tengo que reiniciar. Así aguanta en torno a una hora y se vuelve a bloquear otra vez.

Entiendo que esto es algo que requiere de mucho trabajo de optimización, pero os agradecería si me pudierais decir si hay algún error grave en mi archivo my.ini, o si falta algo importante que debería añadir:

```
[MySQLD]
port=3306
basedir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\
datadir=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plesk\\Databases\\MySQL\\Data
character-set-server=latin1
default-storage-engine=INNODB

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20000M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_thread_concurrency=0

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=5

tmp_table_size=128M


query_cache_size = 0

ft_min_word_len=2
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=OFF
ft_stopword_file = ""

max_connections=10000
old_passwords=0
max_user_connections=10000


slow_query_log = 0
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = slow_log.log

max_allowed_packet=16M
[client]
port=3306
```

He probado con diferentes valores de innodb_buffer_pool_size, desde 20 hasta 70GB, pero en ningún caso sirve para solucionar el problema.

Comment: Es difícil determinar la causa a partir de la configuración. Es necesario revisar cómo se está comportando el servidor, revisar qué porcentaje de los recursos se está usando para disco, memoria y CPU; hay que ver si no hay bloqueos de escritura, ver si se necesitan hacer _dirty reads_. A nivel de aplicación, habría que ver si realmente es necesario disponer de 10000 conexiones en BD. Si se usa un pool de conexiones, uno puede atender cientos de peticiones por segundo con un pool de 50-100 conexiones y abrir más posibles sesiones en BD sólo causa más atascos en a gestión de sesiones.

Comment: ¿Qué ocurrió con este problema? ¿Lo solucionaste? Siento llegar tarde a esta pregunta, pero podría ayudarte con el ajuste.

Answer (score 0):

Ese fichero parece correcto. De todos modos el error no se sabe cual es. Suponemos que es la sobrecarga pero por parte de quién, es lo que necesitas saber.
Revisa los logs de la máquina, tanto a nivel mysql como a nivel apache, iss, o lo que quiera que uses como servicio http. Puede ser falta de memoria disponible para mysql o puede ser que el proveedor de tu máquina virtual te limite las conexiones (Por ejemplo OVH limita a 200 conexiones simultáneas por defecto en sus VPS)

Mientras tanto para descartar la base de datos puedes probar a ejecutar lo siguiente, desde un phpMyAdmin o heidiSQL o lo que uses.

```
show variables like "%max_connections%"
```

Si no te cuadra lo que ves puedes cambiarlo con esto:

```
set global max_connections = 'numero que tú consideres';
```

Pero insisto, hay que leer el log para saber de qué se está quejando, que igual es a otro nivel.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. max_connections me indica 10000, que es lo que puse en el my.ini. Seguiré mirando los logs como dices, a ver si veo algo.

Comment: ¿Lo has subido? Si el pico llega a 25000 sube eso a un número holgado por encima de 25000 y monitoriza los logs, que son los que dan la respuesta siempre